# Passing arguments to a method with cmd module

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods

I'm trying to write my own shell in Python using cmd module and I don't know how to solve my problem even after read a hundreads of topics in the internet.

```
def do_triangle_area(a, h):
    "Calculating tiangle's field"
    print (1/2*a)*h
```

I just want to pass "a" and "h" arguments through the command line by launching a program and when I'm typing

```
$ tiangle_area 5 2
```

It should return me result, but there's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test8.py", line 75, in <module>
    CMD().cmdloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 221, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "test8.py", line 17, in do_triangle_area
    print (a*b)
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I was trying to add a self argument

```
def do_triangle_area(self, a, h):
        "Calculating tiangle's field"
        print (1/2*a)*h
```

But it's not working too:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test8.py", line 75, in <module>
    CMD().cmdloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 221, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
TypeError: do_triangle_area() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Everything is in the one class, cmd module imported. It's everything okay when it's one argument - checked, working brilliant but then it can't calculate anything for me. But why it can't handle more than 1 argument from user? How's it working?

What can I do in this situation? Give me any hints, please because I'm banging my head into the wall...

EDIT: Whole code http://pastebin.com/3EVBbvfN
EDIT2: Paste expired - new paste: http://pastebin.com/3wM021s1

Comment: Include the code for `def onecmd` or where you parse the line

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/3EVBbvfN] I don't know what you're asking for so I'm including whole code

Comment: Please, anyone can help me?

Comment: your pastebin is not valid python: `do_triangle_area` takes in `a` & `b` and uses `a` & `h`.

Comment: No no no that's not the issue. It was a fast paste but that's not the point. My point is how to pass two arguments with cmd module? E.g. calculating triangle area or simply adding two integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not understand what happens, just add traces.

```
def do_triangle_area(a, h):
        "Calculating tiangle's field"
        print(a, type(a), h, type(h))
        print (1/2*a)*h
```

would have shown something like:

```
<__main__.CMD object at 0x...> <class '__main__.CMD'> 2 4 <class 'str'>
```

It is now evident that `do_triangle_area` receives 2 arguments, the Cmd object as self and a single string containing the remaining part of the command. So you must write:

```
def do_triangle(self, line):
    "Calculating tiangle's field"
    # print(self, type(self), line, type(line)) uncomment for debug
    a,h = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
    print (1/2*a)*h
```